# NSOutlineView and Autolayout

Tags: autolayout, nsoutlineview, xcode5

Having recently switched to autolayout in Xcode 5 (and having watched the developer video from WWDC 13), I'm finding things to work pretty well with the exception of a View-Based NSOutlineView.

Before autolayout, this worked. Everything works fine and is in the right location, but now, specifically when I scroll, some of the new entries (and not all of them) end up in the wrong place, always larger and slightly higher.

The problem goes away once they are redrawn, but I don't understand the mechanic for drawing these NSTableCellViews and when they are created by the Outline View. I mean, it looks like they are created at some point, the program is guessing about the proper constraints, and then fixing them after a redraw.

It would be really nice to post an image to explain this, but can someone explain the life cycle of a view in an NSTableView or NSOutlineView?

Answer (score 0):

I had to grapple with that issue myself and I was able to fix it today. This will happen if you are using any content inside an `NSTableCellView` that needs to be resized to fit into its cell or any subview of it. I fixed this problem by using an `NSImage` with the exact same size as a placeholder `NSImage` I added as subview to the `NSTableCellView` on IB. This resizing will break the constraints you added to or expect in this view.